# Highcharts chart doesn't show in jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog, highcharts

I'm trying to show a chart in a jQuery dialog.

I actually do it, but only the first time. When I reload the page and show the dialog, I get only an empty space. Here's my code:

```
function () {
    var dialog = $('#div_id').dialog({
        'autoOpen': false,
        'closeOnEscape':true, 
        'buttons':[{ 
        'text':'OK',
        'click': function() { $(this).dialog('close'); }
        }],
        'modal':true
    });
    $("#show_dialog_button").click(function () {
            dialog.dialog('open');
            var chart = Highcharts.Chart({/*some configs here*/});
            var jqChart = $("#"+chart.options.chart.renderTo);
        HighchartsHelper.autoResizeChart(jqChart,chart);
    }
}
```

I hope somebody can help.

Comment: Are you sure your dialog has been created before it render the chart ?
Can you alert something after open the dialog and see if it's rendered ?

Comment: I create the chart right after .dialog('open') function call, as I have shown in the code snippet above. I assume that the chart is rendered when Highcharts.Chart() method is called and that .dialog() method finishes before calling the chart constructor. Are those asumptions right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have found what the problem is. When a dialog is created it copies the given element and puts it in the body tag. Thus there are more than one elements with the same id. Then on the second call the dialog doesn't know which element to get and show so it just opens. The fix is to remove all those elements except the original one from the DOM. My code looks like this:

```
$("[id='dialog_element']").not("#dialog_parent>#dialog_element").remove();
```

I remove those parasite elements like that for compatibility with IE7 (Maybe all IE7+)